# Get method name of my method's caller

Tags: java, android

I have two methods. In one of them, I call second one. In this second one I need to know name of method, which call this (second) one.

Is this even possible?

```
public class Test {
  public void foo() {
    String m = getCallingMethodName();
  }
  public String getCallingMethodName() {
    return callerMethodName; //should return "foo"
  }
}
```

Comment: While you *can* do it with code such as manouti has provided, I wouldn't be entirely surprised to see if fail due to things like inlining - it would be better to avoid *needing* this if at all possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. You can get the stack trace of the current thread and look at the next one down from the top. (I can provide more detail when I get to a real computer instead of responding from my phone, or someone else can feel free to morph this into an answer). I'd recommend changing your code to not need this though, as it makes your code brittle. Why doesn't the caller just pass in this info as an argument?

Comment: Okey, I am working on Android (Xposed) module. I need to know who calls Android API X. By whom I mean app (package) and exact method/class. Wish I didn't have to do this big hack, but no idea yet how to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

With this you can obtain the current method name:

```
String method_name = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTraceElements[1];
String methodName = stackTraceElement.getMethodName();
```

However this is not guaranteed to return an accurate result, as per the Javadocs of `Thread#getStackTrace()`:

> Some virtual machines may, under some circumstances, omit one or more stack frames from the stack trace. In the extreme case, a virtual machine that has no stack trace information concerning this thread is permitted to return a zero-length array from this method.

You should probably re-think your program design if you want accurate results on all JVM implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are correct, but I thought I'd add a small note of caution. This won't work if you call things using reflection and also it might not get the right stack frame if you have any AOP joinpoints / proxies etc.

For example...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class CallerInfoFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        otherMethod(); // Prints "main"

        Method m = CallerInfoFinder.class.getDeclaredMethod("otherMethod");

        m.invoke(null); // Prints "invoke0"
    }

    private static void otherMethod() {
        System.out.println(new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method shows 3 recent points of Method calling hierarchy in the order of calling them while ignoring 2 most recent methods which includes the following method itself. This is very useful to catch method hierarchy in a program unit where multiple paths access the same location.

```
private static String getRecentSteps() {
    String recentSteps = "";
    StackTraceElement[] traceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    final int maxStepCount = 3;
    final int skipCount = 2;

    for (int i = Math.min(maxStepCount + skipCount, traceElements.length) - 1; i >= skipCount; i--) {
        String className = traceElements[i].getClassName().substring(traceElements[i].getClassName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        recentSteps += " >> " + className + "." + traceElements[i].getMethodName() + "()";
    }

    return recentSteps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getStackTrace() method on the current thread. This returns the call stack in reverse order

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 1; i < stackTraceElements.length && i<=4; i++) {
            StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTraceElements[i];
            System.out.println(stackTraceElement.getClassName() + " Method "
            + stackTraceElement.getMethodName()); 

        }
```